# Are there any incompatibility issues when running cygwin sshd on a windows 2003 domain controller?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssh, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I am asking for incompatibility here.

[Safety was already covered in that question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/270652/how-safe-is-it-to-run-cygwin-sshd-on-a-windows-2003-domain-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there shouldn't be any. Cygwin was made to run on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could also take the Microsoft point of view (you are running DC's after all) and just go with [a more officially supported option, the Subsystems for Unix architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX#Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications_.28SUA.29).  It is obviously [less palatable](https://serverfault.com/questions/178369/interix-sua-ssh-server-any-good), but welcome to the wonderful world of Windows. Haha.

Comment: they will switch to a linux or bsd kernel sooner or later ;-)